# How can I check for a TeamID when logging in and if it is null redirect the login to another page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I am using identity 2.0 and so the login and registration was already set up. I added a TeamID to the AspNetUsers table. When logging as well as checking the email and password I want it to check the TeamID. If the TeamID is null I want to redirect it to the "Index", "Teams" page so a user selects a team. If the TeamID is not null I want it to go to the home page. This is the code for the login

```
// POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return View(model);
            }

            //This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            //To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply need to look the user up by their email and check the team ID before signing them in:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
if (user != null && !user.TeamID.HasValue)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Teams");
}

//This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
//To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this partly works. It checks for the id and redirects me to the Teams page if there is no id but does not log the user in. I want to the user to be logged in even if they don't have a TeamID so then they can select one.

Comment: Just move the code to after successful login, then.